# How do we conclude whether an answer is correct?

Tags: discussion, voting, accepted-answer

Stack Overflow is very useful for getting answers to our questions and give answer to other questions to help others.

Many users accept the answer sometimes so that we conclude that either that answer satisfied the questioner's requirement to a certain extent, but what if answers are there, but none are accepted?

My concern is if anyone gets their answer from Stack Overflow, then s/he should have to accept it or if he or she got any other solution, then s/he should have to post on Stack Overflow.

This would be really helpful to all SO users.

Comment: Votes are often a good proxy for quality. Thats what they are for

Comment: 'should have to accept it' how do you manage that? How do you distinguish between a clear answer that should be accepted and hasn't after a long time, and a not-so-good answer to a question that still is missing a good answer?

Comment: There is a possible case that the question is answered before the OP can accept it. He tries the answer and it works, *and the OP leaves and never comes back to SO, without giving any indicator that the answer really works*. Meanwhile, as already stated by other, votes are generally a good representation if the answer is helpful (that is, working) or not.

Comment: Read the warranty at the bottom of the page.  (And I've seen many woefully incorrect answers "accepted".)

Answer (score 2):

[You are not obligated to accept any answer that is posted to your question.](//stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

If someone tells you that, they're trying to get you to accept their answer so that they get 15 extra reputation points.

*Only* accept the answer that helped you the most or, if none truly helped you, don't accept one at all. Instead, try clarifying your question or telling the answerer(s) in comments why their answer(s) did not help. Of all of the things on Stack Overflow, accepting an answer is one of the things you have the most control over.

Otherwise, a simple upvote will signify a post's usefulness, and if you have multiple answers, it's a way to thank each answerer for their efforts (don't just do it to thank them, though: only upvote if the post is *actually useful*).

---

Now, if you come across a post on Stack Overflow that *isn't yours* and you're looking for a way to tell which answer is the best, votes are *generally* (not always) a good measure of the best answer: if an answer is upvoted, that usually means that someone who frequents the tag (and therefore likely knows about the topic) upvoted the answer as a way of recognizing its usefulness/correctness.

Another possibility is that someone having the same problem came across it and it solved their problem, so they upvoted it in gratitude. Either way, the answer was upvoted for its positive contribution to the question, so it is likely (but, again, not always) the best answer to the question.

Don't worry about which answer is accepted: as I've mentioned above, the accepted answer is generally the one that helped the OP the most, who may or may not have had the same problem as you. If no answer is accepted, it usually doesn't mean much because the OP either didn't know how to accept an answer or got an answer too quickly to be able to accept it and did not come back after the required waiting period to accept it.

Comment: Agreed, but on "if none truly helped you, don't accept one at all" it should be noted that this hypothetical OP may (1) comment on the answer(s) and say *why* it did not help, and/or (2) re-read the question for possible ambiguities.

Comment: @Jongware True: added.